# Gradle execute command lines in custom task

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-task

In my gradle file I defined the following task:

```
task text_example <<
{
   //?!? commandLine ''
   println 'Fam Flinstone'
}
```

I want to put inside this task some commands line. How can I do that ?

I'm using a library to automatically publish in google play. My project is based on Product Flavors and I need to pass in terminal command line by command line for every and each one of my flavors. So I want to pass all commands line in `test_example` task.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You basically have two major convenient options:

1. Use Gradle [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task type

   ```
    task fooExec(type: Exec) {
        workingDir "${buildDir}/foo"
        commandLine 'echo', 'Hello world!'
        doLast {
            println "Executed!"
        }
    }
   ```
2. Use Gradle [Project.exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec-groovy.lang.Closure-) method

   ```
    task execFoo {
        doLast {
            exec {
                workingDir "${buildDir}/foo"
                executable 'echo'
                args 'Hello world!'
            }
            println "Executed!"
        }
    }
   ```

In both cases inside the closure you can specify execution parameters using methods of [ExecSpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/process/ExecSpec.html).
Standard output and error output from the executed commands will be redirected to stdout and stderr of the gradle process.

#### Edit @2022-07-07

There's an important caveat mentioned in the comments below: Gradle's `exec` does **not** evaluate a command line like a shell (e.g. Bash on Linux or CMD on Windows) would, it simply executes specified executable with the provided arguments.

This has some *hidden* consequences that one needs to keep in mind:

1. To execute a 'command', one needs to specify a valid existing executable file.

   The most common case when this comes up is when trying to use 'commands' that are implemented on a specific OS by a shell and do not have an available implementation in a form of an executable file (e.g. `echo` and similar commands on Windows).
2. There are no 'fancy' features supported by modern shells like streams redirects and similar (although you can still redirect *stdout* of one process to *stdin* of another using two separate `exec` invocations with custom IO configuration).
3. User-defined aliases (e.g. defined in `~/.bsahrc`) are **not** available.

##### FIY: do not actually do it!

The 'common' work around to 'easily' get a modern shell's functionality inside Gradle would be to actually run a shell process and provide the command line as its argument, e.g. if using Bash:

```
task shellExec(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "${buildDir}/foo"
    commandLine 'bash', '-c', "echo 'Hello world!'"
}
```

However, this approach instantly binds the build script to a particular platform making it inoperable on platforms that do not have that particular shell (e.g. above example would not work on Windows).

Comment: Does not work for newer Gradle. Need to use `doLast { }` closure instead of `<<`

Comment: Good catch! They deprecated `Taks.leftShift` in favor of `Taks.doLast` in 3.2.

Comment: Updated my answer to be compatible with recent Gradle versions.

Comment: Comment for Windows - using exec it's like running executable. So to run command line programs like echo you need:
`exec {
            executable = "cmd"
            args = listOf("/C", "echo Hello World")
        }`

Comment: Good point! Although, I must add that the "_using exec it's like running executable_" statement is true for all OSes: `exec` does **not** evaluate a command line like a shell (e.g. Bash or Windows' CMD) would, it simply executes specified executable with the provided arguments.

Comment: The reason the above samples work on *nix and do not work on Windows is because *nix systems have basic shell commands such as `echo` available as actual executable files.